# Convert Text Data into SVMFile format for Spam Classification?

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, bigdata, apache-spark-mllib

How can I convert Text Data into LibSVM file format for training the model for spam classification.
Are SVMFiles already Labeled ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SVM format is neither required or that useful. It is used in Apache Spark ML example, only because it can be map directly to the required format.

> Are SVMFiles already Labeled ?

Not necessarily, but Spark can read only labeled variant.

In practice you should use `org.apache.spark.ml.feature` tools to extract relevant features from your data.

You can follow [the documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features.html) as well as a number of questions on SO.,